# Compute product of two integers as lower and higher half

Tags: c++, integer, bit-manipulation, multiplication, integer-overflow

Computing the product of two `n`-bits integers requires a `2n`-bits result to do not overflow.

Well, how would be possible to compute the product of two `n`-bits integers as two `n` bits integers `res0` and `res1`, where `res0` contains the lower half of the result and `res1` contains the higher one?